# Stop ant script from running when I restart eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant

I have some legacy ant projects in my eclipse workspace (ouch).

To add insult to injury, these projects' ant build scripts start running each time I restart eclipse.... how do I disable this annoyance?

Comment: Possibly `Project > Build Automatically` is running during the restart.

Comment: Typically, this happens when an Ant Builder is configured in one or more projects' properties. Have you checked your project properties in "right-click > Properties > Builders" ?

Answer (score 0):

In the Progress tab see at the bottom right corner it shows the progress bar, click the green progress bar which will display the square red button to stop the ant compilation.